# NPM - módulos e proxy

Tags: node.js, proxy

Boa tarde

Estou tentando instalar o módulo do ibm watson no meu app, mas recebo erro abaixo

Estou na rede da empresa... O que queria saber é se consigo "driblar" ou configurar esse proxy de alguma forma

> C:\Users\nascimento\Desktop\watson>npm i --save
>   watson-developer-cloud 
>   npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND npm ERR! errno
>   ENOTFOUND npm ERR! network request to
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/watson-developer-cloud failed, reason:
>   getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443 npm
>   ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity. npm
>   ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network
>   settings. npm ERR! network npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy,
>   please make sure that the npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set
>   properly.  See: 'npm help config'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\nascimento.juliana\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-06-25T18_25_10_407Z-debug.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode configurar o proxy do NPM com os comandos

```
npm config set http_proxy http://usuario:senha@proxy.company.com:porta
npm config set https_proxy  http://usuario:senha@proxy.company.com:porta
```

Comment: A porta é a mesma do servidor do meu app?

Comment: a porta é a do proxy da empresa

Comment: por que rankeou negativamente?

Comment: não fui eu que rankei como negativa O.o